# How to create excel report dynamically with multiple sheets using ireport

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I want to create excel report dynamically which has multiple sheet is it possible to create using iReport 4.5.0?

Comment: have you googled anything?

Comment: Yes, I searched whole day. That's my first time for jasper report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes.

It is possible to create multiple sheets dynamically.

Use iReport properties field

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row
```

> Custom element property specifying if a sheet will break after the row displaying that element. It is very useful especially when displaying each report's group on a separate sheet is intended.

for full list of property fields how to use property. visit [this](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/properties-how-use-additional-properties-build-enhanced-reports) page

Complete API of property can be found [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html)(Reference) and [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html)(Index)